# C program using char* crashing

Tags: c, pointers, char

The goal is to count all the vowels from a char* the user puts in. The program has other functions and this is called from main.
I have also included stdio.h, stdbool.h, and string.h

```
 char* countWord;
 int vowels;
 printf("Type the word to count vowels:");
 scanf("%s", &countWord);
 vowels = vowelCount(countWord);
 printf("%d", vowels);
```

The following is the function I was used. I also tried strlen(string) which caused a crash as well.

```
int vowelCount(char* string){
    int vowels;
    int i;
    int size;
    printf("function entered");

    for (; *string; string++){
        if (string[i] == 'a'){
            vowels++;
        } else if(string[i] == 'e'){
            vowels++;
        } else if(string[i] == 'i'){
            vowels++;
        } else if(string[i] == 'o'){
            vowels++;
        } else if(string[i] == 'u'){
            vowels++;
        }

    }
    return vowels;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to C but have experience in other languages.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the pointer pointing to? Is it a valid address? Be sure to initialize/assign pointers before using.

Comment: I thought char* countWord; initialized it

Comment: `char *countWord` (at least, for a variable of automatic storage duration, which occurs when in a function block) defines an uninitialised pointer.   Accessing its value, or dereferencing [which accesses the value and then tries to access what is at that address] in any way (e.g. reading what is at the address, writing to that address) gives undefined behaviour.   The only action that is well-defined for an uninitialised pointer is assigning its value (e.g. to an actual address).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exercising *undefined behavior*...

You have not allocated any space for the pointer to point at, so when you're trying to use it, the behavior is undefined.

Simply make some space for it:

```
char buffer[1000];
char* countWord = buffer;
```

and there's another mistake:

```
scanf("%s", &countWord);
            ^
```

You shouldn't use an address of (`&`) operator here. Just drop it. You're reading a string into the target of the pointer, not the pointer itself.

Also note that you're doing some mixed code in your function. You're using an uninitialized variable `i`, yet that seems unnecessary since you're incrementing the pointer `string`. So you want to drop `i` and change the if statement to

```
if (*string == 'a')
```

And be sure to initialize `vowel` as well:

```
int vowel = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the scanf man page, the format specifier %s:

"Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and the array must be large enough to accept all the sequence and the terminating NUL character."

The pointer your code provides matching the sole %s specifier, however, is the *address* of the variable declared as a pointer to char: &countWord is of type pointer to pointer to char. Thus, scanf writes (or attempts to write) the matched sequence to a location sized for a pointer to char, not necessarily the sequence length + null terminator. This may thus write into unallocated memory, which is undefined behavior (and oftentimes, a segfault). Simply removing the address-of operator will not suffice on its own to resolve the issue, either, because simply declaring a pointer to char does not allocate the space for the characters you presumably want said pointer to point to at some point.

What you must do to read a string using scanf as you have attempted to is to ensure that sufficient space is allocated to store the sequence you will read, then pass scanf a pointer to that space. These could be allocated statically:

```
char countWord[512]; // Assumes input sequence will consist of no more than 511 characters, since space is needed for the terminating NUL character
```

Or dynamically:

```
char* countWord = malloc(sizeof(char) * 512); // Same size as the above, so input still must be no more than 511 characters, but dynamically allocated so will need to be explicitly freed later to avoid leaking memory
```

Given the space is allocated and sufficient, you can then pass countWord (which defined in either of the manners shown above, is effectively a pointer to char, no address-of required*)
If the sequence your scanf call is reading as input is under some defined input restriction, you can pass scanf a pointer to sufficient allocated space for the maximum allowable input sequence size, guaranteeing the read sequence will not exceed the allocated space.

This, however, depends on the input following said limits. Better would be for your code to limit how much it might read, so it really is guaranteed that you won't access unallocated memory, even if your input source decides not to behave as expected. scanf provides a mechanism to do this by including a field width with the specifier, e.g.:

```
scanf("%511s", countWord); // Reads at most 511 bytes of input into the location pointed to by countWord, plus the NUL terminator.
```

Obviously, instead of 511 characters of input you would choose a suitable number that all valid inputs to the program should fall within.

The other answer noting that variables should be initialized before being read from is also true, but crashes specifically are more likely to result from interacting with unallocated memory than allocated but merely uninitialized memory (not that reading from the latter isn't undefined behavior).

*Technically there are some differences between a char array declared explicitly as an array and a pointer to char, but those differences are not particularly relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your lack of memory allocation for `countWord` was already mentioned in other answers.

But you also have a problem with usage of uninitialized variable while counting the vowels.
You iterate using `string` pointer and add some random value `i` on top of that.

```
int vowelCount(char* string){
  int i;  // <<=== not initialized, holding ramdon garbage value

  for (; *string; string++){
      if (string[i] == 'a'){  // << adding random index to pointer.
...
```